# SQL full text search odity

Tags: sql

Hoping someone can shed some light on an issue I have.

So I have a table with email, name and a few other details in. Its full text indexed and I can happily search the catalog for name, email or any other fields using the search modify as '"' + @searchString + '*"' which works perfect for all columns. Except it seems, for email addresses where they end in @me.com. Removing the * works for these but breaks the other columns. Any ideas as to why @me.com doesn't work with a wildcard search and what I can do to fix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What database is it? oracle, sql server, mySql ?

Comment: Sorry, been away. 

Its a SQL database. It was a little hard to give a reproductive example due to it being from a full text catalog. 

thanks